# Outputting objects from a class

Tags: python, class, object, printing, output

I'm trying to output details of an object, in this case (a person), whole code below

```
class Person:

    person = Person()

    def __init__(self):
        self._first_name = str ()
        self._last_name = str ()
        self._day = int ()
        self._month = int ()
        self._year = int ()

    def set_name(self, forename, surname):
        self._first_name = forename
        self._last_name = surname

    def get_name(self):
        return self._first_name + " " + self._last_name

    def set_dob(self, d, m, y):
        if self._is_valid_date(d, m):
            self._day = int(d)
            self._month = int(m)
            self._year = int(y)
        else:
            return "Invalid date entered."

    def get_dob(self):
        return "{0}-{1}-{2}".format(self._day, self._month, self._year)

    def get_age_at(self, d, m, y):
        age = -1
        if self.is_valid_date(d, m) and self._is_after_dob(d, m, y):
            age = y - self._year
            if (m < self._month) or (m == self._month and d < self._day):
                age -= 1
        return age

    def get_details(self):
        return "{0}, {1}".format(self.get_name(), self.get_dob())

john = Person()
john.set_name("John", "Lennon")
john.set_dob(8,10,1940)

print (john.get_details())
```

I expect, John Lennon 8 10 1940 to be output

I get:

```
   line 1, in <module>
    class Person:
   line 3, in Person
    john = Person()
 NameError: name 'Person' is not defined
```

Any ideas? pretty new to python so any help would be awesome thank you!

Comment: 1) Your indentation is incorrect. Please ensure that the indentation in your code snippet matches your actual program. Remember, in Python, whitespace is significant. Changing your indentation changes the syntax of your program. 2) What do you expect `person = Person()` to do on line 3?

Comment: Remove your line `person=Person()` at the top.

Comment: Note, your error does not match your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has three errors, as far as I can see:

- The indentation isn't correct. All of the code after `class Person:` and before `john = Person()` should be indented to the right by one stop or, conventionally, four spaces.
- The line `person = Person()` is incorrect. Delete it.
- You have not defined `_is_valid_date()`. Add this to your class definition.

  ```
  def _is_valid_date(self, *args):
      return True
  ```

Additionally, many find the use of "setters" and "getters" in Python bad style. Consider, when you learn how, using `@propterty` to get and set your internal state variables.

Comment: The class definition is also missing a `_is_after_dob()` method.

Comment: True, but that is not necessarily an error in *this* program. This program never references `_is_after_dob()`.